# Disable external window activation

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to automate application but on some automation tasks application activates its own main window.

This interrupts automation behavior. Is there a way to trap a message and properly disable window from activating itself.

What i have tried so far is subclassing the main window and intercepting

```
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
        return false;
    case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
        return false;
    case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        return false;
    case WM_ACTIVATE:
        return false;
    case WM_MOUSEACTIVATE:
        return false;
    case WM_NCACTIVATE: 
            return false;
```

This doesnt give any good results because the window still activates itself even its subclassed and false is returned for each of this messages.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're subclassing the window unless it's your own application. If it is your own, can't you just change the application code to avoid activating the window if the action being performed is invoked through your automation API?

Comment: why? this would break the user experience. if a user alt-tabs to your application, what the OS should do? or maybe you mean you want to write a service, or a taskbar application?

Comment: No, its not my application, i am trying to automate external app. Its external application(as mentioned in title) that needs automation assistance but during this automation tasks sometimes the topmost(main window) activates itself and that interrupts automation experience.

Comment: @VojislavStojkovic I am subclassing it by injecting dll in its process - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces